# Emacs: How can I get M-x sql-oracle to open a new buffer

Tags: oracle, emacs, sqlplus

I was using Emacs 21  and I occasionally needed an sql prompt for different oracle schema's. In Emacs I could pretty easy rename a buffer enter `M-x sql-oracle` and a new *SQL* buffer would pop up.

Now I'm using Emacs 24 and after renaming the buffer hitting `M-x sql-oracle` again the renamed buffer gets focus instead of opening a new buffer.

I looked in my `.emacs` and also went over the SQL group but till so far I haven't found anything?

Answer (score 3):

After doing some more google I found it

http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2010-12/msg02194.html

Basically do `C-u M-x sql-oracle`